# Preinstall android apps without system permissions

Tags: applications

I want to make an android image with preinstalled apps. But I want them to not have access to the extended permissions available when /system/app/ installed. How can I make that sure?

Comment: Have you looked about [tag:nandroid] backup? It creates image for you.

Comment: What version of Android is this ? And does this image have root and init.d support ?